# Using Netbanx API

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, netbanx-api

I'm trying to use the Netbanx API and i always get {"error":{"code":401,"message":"Not authorised"}} I dont know what I am doing wrong.

```
var url = "https://api.test.netbanx.com/hosted/v1/orders";
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    headers: { 
    "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa("devcentre4157:B-qa2-0-54b6431d-302c021451aabe02869ba82a4a4253d8b2a170d7950d228b021448948677e24be8180f945f1af2b583676c353b9f") 
    },
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: "{merchantRefNum:'89983943',currencyCode:'CAD',totalAmount:'10'}",
    success: function (data) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    },
    error: function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

Comment: WTH is netbanx / netbanx API, and if that's the topic of the question, why isn't it tagged?

Comment: https://developer.optimalpayments.com/en/ and need 1500 reputation to add a new tag

Answer (score 2):

I verified your code in and receive 401 as well.

Credentials is good, I did curl request and it's return data

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -u devcentre4157:B-qa2-0-54b6431d-302c021451aabe02869ba82a4a4253d8b2a170d7950d228b021448948677e24be8180f945f1af2b583676c353b9f \
     https://api.test.netbanx.com/hosted/v1/orders \
  -d '{
          "merchantRefNum" : "89983943",
          "currencyCode"   : "CAD",
          "totalAmount"    : 10
      }'  

{"currencyCode":"CAD","id":"27HBQC4JI28QISA1LM","link":[{"rel":"hosted_payment","uri":"https://pay.test.netbanx.com/hosted/v1/payment/53616c7465645f5f9d3670f3f61d1664e3c0db218618a55369145e7577df013ab0691c526e56a445"},{"rel":"self","uri":"https://devcentre4157:B-qa2-0-54b6431d-302c021451aabe02869ba82a4a4253d8b2a170d7950d228b021448948677e24be8180f945f1af2b583676c353b9f@api.test.netbanx.com/hosted/v1/orders/27HBQC4JI28QISA1LM"},{"rel":"resend_callback","uri":"https://devcentre4157:B-qa2-0-54b6431d-302c021451aabe02869ba82a4a4253d8b2a170d7950d228b021448948677e24be8180f945f1af2b583676c353b9f@api.test.netbanx.com/hosted/v1/orders/27HBQC4JI28QISA1LM/resend_callback"}],"merchantRefNum":"89983943","mode":"live","totalAmount":10,"type":"order"}
```

I used DHC chrome plugin for one more check - it works as well. SO I am pretty sure there is Cross Domain problem with your JavaScript example. Netbanx just does not allow to do Cross Domain request to API.

[image]

Comment: Yeah i know thats is what the error code says but my credential are good. i have taken them from the my account page at developer.optimalpayments.com

Comment: you are correct - credentials is ok, I did curl and it's work. Maybe some cross site reference problem ? It's not a good idea to do request like this from the client javascript - you credentials is open.

Answer (score 0):

Normally in these situations the issue is how the key is encoded. it is posisble that when copying and pasting there are spaces at the beginning or end. The credentials do look valid.